# Object expected error upon setting WinJS.UI.ListView DataSource

Tags: listview, windows-8, winjs

I'm getting the below stack trace when I try to setup a ListView control with a static datasource of an array of objects. The application errors out in ui.js on this line:

```
var rendered = WinJS.Promise.as(this.renderer(itemForRendererPromise, recycledElement)).
            then(WinJS.UI._normalizeRendererReturn);
```

> TypeError: Object expected    at renderItemAsync
>   (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:20074:9)    at Anonymous
>   function (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:22477:54)    at
>   _renderItem (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:10557:9)    at _elementForItem (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:10637:13)    at _itemFromItemPromise
>   (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:10333:9)    at _itemAtIndex
>   (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:10341:9)    at Anonymous
>   function (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:17393:21)    at
>   Promise_ctor (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1865:17)    at
>   _LayoutCommon_measureItems (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:17338:17)    at Anonymous
>   function (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:17296:29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this was because I had moved the list item template (WinJS.Binding.Template) I was using to the bottom of he HTML page. It appears if you don't place the template before the listview, it will throw this error. Pretty weird but at least it's an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks, just had the same issue and this was the ONLY search result to come back on it in google.